# Change parameters of a function in Python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, parameters

Is it possible (and if so, how) to change the parameters of a function after definition?

Example:

```
from inspect import signature
def f(a, b, c):
    print(a + b + c)

for i in signature(f).parameters:
    print(i)

changeparameters(f, "d", "e")
print()

for i in signature(f).parameters:
    print(i)
```

Would output:

```
a
b
c

d
e
```

Comment: Just curious. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also curious: how do you want to call the function after it has been changed from taking 3 parameters to 2?

Comment: I have realised I was going about a problem in completely the wrong way, and so I will close this question as I do not think it is helpful (I'm fairly sure it isn't possible, and for good reason, it doesn't make sense).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

Just re `def` the function name with the new parameters - since the will not be used by the original you would need to anyway.